# Using ASP.Net C#, DropDownList and Redirecting? Without using button event

Tags: asp.net

I have a DropDownList with several options. I want the user to select an option and the page should redirect as user selected the dropdown option without using button

Answer (score 0):

Set `AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="YourMethodName"` and in `YourMethodName(){}` add for `Response.Redirect` to certain pages dependant on the selected value.

**Example:**

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" ID="YourMethod" OnSelectedIndexChanged="YourMethod_OnSelectedIndexChanged" />

protected void YourMethod_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        switch (YourMethod.SelectedValue)
        {
            case "first":
                Response.Redirect("url");
                break;
        }
    }
```